# How to remove border of a dynamically colored search bar in Swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, border, swift5, searchbar

[Click to see my current search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iONtg.png)

What I am trying to do is to remove the two lines on top and at the bottom of the search bar (without changing anything else). I have tried using

```
searchBar.backgroundImage(UIImage)
```

but that makes the inside of the bar white, which is not what I want. I tried setting the style of the search bar to be minimalist, but am not sure how I can make the bar tint dynamic (previous dynamic-coloring code doesn't work anymore)

I have researched a lot and saw similar questions where people are ok with the search bar being white, or not having dynamic color. For the app I'm working on (kind of like a todo-list), the search bar in the view controllers with items under each category will have a different color, depending on the color of the category. Therefore, the color of the search bar is dynamic.

Is there anyway to just remove the two border lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

searchBar.backgroundImage is not a function.

Not sure how you did that without xcode giving you an error.